# Form Data not capturing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the below DEMO to set value for checkboxes as "0" or "1" based on selection of checboxes. The below code is working for one checkbox but If I create multiple checkboxes, it is not working for new ones. How to make it work for all checkboxes.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Checkbox
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

    function check() {
        if (input.checked) {
            var a = "1";
        } else {
            var a = "0";
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result ' + a;
    }
    input.onchange = check;
    check();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxjnx45q/3/)

Comment: Is JQuery an option? It would make this task trivial, I think...

Comment: @anandbookletS, are you allowed/familiar with JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"/>
</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">

$('#checkbox1').change(function() 
{
        if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
            alert("checked-1");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("unchecked-1");    
        }
});

$('#checkbox2').change(function() 
{
        if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
            alert("checked-2");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("unchecked-2");    
        }
});

$('#checkbox3').change(function() 
{
        if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
            alert("checked-3");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("unchecked-3");    
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: When you checked event is fire and check checkbox is checked or not and i display alert there, there you can you your coding as per your requirement

Comment: Hi Paresh. Thanks. The above code is what I am looking for.  I want to set value to the checkbox selected. For example, If I select checkbox1 the value of checkbox1 should be set as "1" else "0". Can you help to rewrite the code in place of alert.

Comment: Put this line on alert document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = "1"; and else part is document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = "0" for every condition and please up vote if i help you

Comment: I have added as you instructed. But the values are not captured in form data. Do I need assign the value from innerHTML to input id.??

<input name="Maxi" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>

Comment: Did you check my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

JavaScript:

```
  window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
   // alert(input);
    function check() {
        if (this.checked) {
            var a = "1";
        } else {
            var a = "0";
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result ' + a;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++){
        if(input[i]) input[i].onchange = check;
    }

    check();
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Checkbox<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Checkbox<br/>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" />Checkbox<br/>

<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qxjnx45q/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you want pure JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); //<-- get all checkboxes
    var l = chks.length;
    while (l--) {
        chks[l].onchange = count;
    }
};

var count = function () {
    var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); //<-- get all checkboxes
    var l = chks.length,
        cnt = 0;
    while (l--) {
        if (chks[l].checked) {
            chks[l].value = '1';
            cnt++;
        } else {
            chks[l].value = '0';
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = cnt;
};
```